# How to tune a Delete query?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a data from the table whose primary key is being referred by several tables with large data. I have tried a query below which is taking a lot of time to execute then I thought of dropping the constraints and rebuilding them, but is there any alternative for this like writing some code in an anonymous block to perform better!!. Please let me know your suggestions.

```
DELETE FROM <table_name1> a
    WHERE 
    a.status='I'
    AND NOT EXISTS  
            (SELECT b.id
            FROM <table_name2> b
            WHERE a.id=b.id)
    AND NOT EXISTS  
            (SELECT c.id 
            FROM <table_name3> c
            WHERE a.id=c.id);       
    COMMIT;
```

Thank you,

Pradeep

Comment: Check the execution plan

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all foreign key columns are indexed. This can make a huge difference. Here is a link to a blog entry that describes ways to find non-indexed foreign key columns.

http://blog.go-faster.co.uk/2007/10/tm-locking-checking-for-missing-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

I think CBO will do hash join with *TABLE ACCESS FULL* to table_name1 and *INDEX FAST FULL SCAN* to table_name2 and table_name3. Maybe will be better to precalc all IDs using only *INDEX FAST FULL SCAN* and after than delete selected rows using INDEX ACCESS:

```
declare
  v_list is table of number;
begin
  select t1.id 
     bulk collect into v_list 
  from <<table_name1>> t1
  left join <<table_name2>> t2 on (t1.id = t2.id)
  left join <<table_name3>> t3 on (t1.id = t3.id)
  where nvl(t2.id,t3.id) is null;

  forall i in v_list.first..v_list.last
  delete from <<table_name1>> t
  where t.id = v_list(i)
    and t.status = 'I';

  commit;  
end;
```

Please try this/ But I'm not sure that it helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make the subqueries independent from surrounding statement. Therefore the subqueries are always the same, only need to be calculated once and the statement might be optimized better.

```
DELETE FROM <table_name1> a
    WHERE 
    a.status='I'
    AND a.id NOT IN
            (SELECT b.id
            FROM <table_name2> b)
    AND a.id NOT IN
            (SELECT c.id 
            FROM <table_name3> c);
```